# Convert from bigint to varchar without leading 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to use a bigint value as part of a string construction, but I can't figure out how to get from bigint to to varchar without having a leading 0

```
declare @a bigint = 167830720612159876
select convert(varchar(32), convert(varbinary, @a), 2)
```

This gives me `02544126B47C5184`, but I want `2544126B47C5184'

Basically I want the conversion from bigint to varbinary to omit the leading 0 so that it is left out of the string representation.

Comment: The zero is there because each pair of hex digits represents one byte.

Comment: Is this SQL Server?

Comment: *"Is this SQL Server? "* the SQL tag seams to be very heavy misused tag on this website @RobertHarvey Most think that the SQL tag on this website relates to SQL Server (MSSQL) but it is not it is about ANSI/ISO SQL standard code..  But i think you right it looks like valid SQL Server [code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=afa4bb1d95d8bb27f373bfb5e90834c7)

Comment: Sorry yes this is Sql Server

Comment: What should be the result for zero?  What do you want to see for a negative number?.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create function dbo.BigintToHex(@X bigint)
returns varchar(20) as
begin
  declare @H varchar(20) = ''
  declare @D varchar(16) = '0123456789ABCDEF'
  if @X = 0 
    set @H = '0'
  if @X < 0 
    set @H = '-' + dbo.BigintToHex(-@X)
  else
    while @X > 0 
      begin
        set @H = SUBSTRING(@D,@X % 16+1,1) + @H
        set @X = @X / 16
      end
  return @H
end
go

select dbo.BigintToHex(-167830720612159876)
```

Comment: Was this helpful at all?